# Is it possible to control Airbus H175 Rescue Helicopter 42145 via the app?

Tags: technic, powered-up, remote-control, set-modification

Has anyone used a [Technic Hub 88012](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=88012-1)

[image]

and not the [Powered Up battery box](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb1295c01) that comes with the set?

[image]

I would love to get it controlled via the app.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would make a lot of sense, since the different functions are activated with mechanical switches.
Unlike the Caterpillar D11, this set only has one motor that is shared using clutches, so an app wouldn't control much.

Comment: I realised it would take over parts to get functionality,but just wondering if anyone had done it

Comment: You'd need additional motors to control the clutches, I'm afraid there isn't enough spare room for that in the model

Comment: Thanks, and sausages, I did think that might be the case. I was hoping to get it working with lights, and warning speaker, but lego are yet to create that part.  I hoped to and a sensor so it could detect the ground and either lower wheels, or say pull up and increase speed as it takes off, but probably just a dream thanks everyone one for all the help

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can get an appropriate software profile to control it with, <s>I don't see any other possible hurdles.</s>

**Edit:** As Joost mentions, the accessibility of the power button could very well be an issue though.

Comment: Other issue is access to the power button. The beam connecting the front and back landing gear wheel is directly above the button. Maybe there are other parts in this area that block the access

Comment: Yes thought that the power button might be hard to access, and from the sounds of it, the bottom would need a bit of a redesign